# O Google, where art thou Linux special search?

Tags: google-search

Google Linux search has disappeared. Were there any announcements by Google regarding it?

**google.com/linux** was a Linux specific search, part of a set of Special Searches along with UncleSam and BSD. It helped filter out non-Linux results when search. (All the other special searches are gone as well.)

What happened to **google.com/linux**?

Comment: For those how don't know google.com/linux - what was/is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like they've done away with the "special searches" feature they used to offer, which affects /linux and /unclesam among others. You can read more here:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Web%20Search/thread?tid=68eef4f9581f51bf&hl=en

Unfortunately it does not explain why it just states that going to /webhp is the intended behavior and not a bug / misconfiguration.

For those that don't know, you could go to google.com/linux and perform a search that returned linux-centric results.

Answer (score 5):

You can still achieve nearly exactly the same result (minus the logo) by prefixing your searches with "linux". The website was never really more than a shortcut for that in the first place.